# Update таблицы на которой trigger мутация таблицы

Tags: oracle, plsql, update, триггер

Привет, я знаю, что подобные вопросы часто поднимались, но все равно до конца не могу разобраться в этой теме. Аптейда таблицы на которой есть триггер

Имеем 2 таблицы:

- **Sale_income**:

  ```
  | item |income |create_user |create_date        |last_update_user | update_time|
  |------|-------|------------|-------------------|-----------------|------------|
  | 1    |  100  |duck        |05-19-2016         |human            |05-19-2016  |
  | 2    |  250  |dog         |05-19-2016         |human            |05-19-2016  |
  | 3    |  210  |cat         |05-20-2016         |human            |05-19-2016  |
  ```
- **Sale_income_audit**:

  ```
  | item |change_id|last_inc|new_inc   |user_update|update_date|operation   |
  |------|---------|--------|----------|-----------|-----------|------------|
  | 1    |  1      |null    |05-19-2016|duck       |05-19-2016 |I           |
  | 2    |  2      |null    |05-19-2016|dog        |05-19-2016 |I           |
  | 3    |  33     |null    |05-20-2016|cat        |05-19-2016 |I           |
  ```

Когда кто-то делает `INSERT`, `DELETE` или `UPDATE` таблицы **Sale_income**, соответствующее поле добавляется в таблицу **Sale_income_audit** с соответствующий операцией (колонка `operation`). Но в этот же момент поля в основной таблице (`last_update`) должны тоже измениться. И тут мы встречаемся с проблемой мутирующей таблицы.

Я решил это следующим образом: создал пакет с тремя переменными и двумя триггерами. В триггере на апдейт **Sale_income** данные о времени и пользователе заносятся в переменные. А после апдейта в другом триггере идет обновление нужных полей.

Пакет:

```
create or replace package Sale_income_var as
    v_old_income BINARY_INTEGER := null;
    v_new_income BINARY_INTEGER := null;
     v_item      BINARY_INTEGER := null;
END Sale_income_var;
```

Триггеры:

1. Первый:

   ```
   create or replace trigger audit_income_IUD
     after insert or update or delete on Sale_income
       for each row
   begin  
       .
       .                
   elsif updating then  
           Sale_income_var.v_old_income  := :old.income;
           Sale_income_var.v_new_income  := :new.income;                     
                if  Sale_income_var.v_item is null then                      
           Sale_income_var.v_item := :old.item;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Sale_income_var.v_item);
               end if;
        .
        .
   end if;
   end audit_income_IUD;
   ```
2. Второй:

   ```
   create or replace trigger  sale_income_au
     after update of income on Sale_income
    begin 
      update Sale_income set last_update_user = user, last_update_date = sysdate
          where item = Sale_income_var.v_item;     
      INSERT into Sale_income_audit   (item, 
                                     change_id, 
                                     last_income, 
                                     new_income, 
                                     user_update, 
                                     update_date, 
                                     operation)
                                VALUES (Sale_income_var.v_item,
                                        auto_incr.NEXTVAL, 
                                        Sale_income_var.v_old_income, 
                                        Sale_income_var.v_new_income,
                                        user,
                                        sysdate,
                                        'U');                         
                Sale_income_var.v_item := null;
       end sale_income_au;
   ```

Это работает, только я чувствую, что это не верное решение. Да и эта магия с переменными тоже не гуд, я прав?

Что бы вы тут исправили и как бы вышли из такой ситуации? 
Спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы слишком искусственно создали ситуацию мутации таблицы. Давать Update на ту же таблицу на которую написан сам триггер иногда надо, но это скорее касается ситуаций кода при обновлении одной строки таблицы надо менять какие либо другие строки этой же таблицы.

Если вам все таки очень надо делать именно так, то вам надо создать дополнительную таблицу и в первом триггере ("*for each row*") сохранять в этой таблице нужную информацию, например ID меняющихся записей. Во втором триггере на основе этой таблицы делаете необходимые update и удаляете записи из таблицы с ID.

Дело в том, что если на таблицу дается массовый update, т.е. изменяющий несколько записей за раз, то в начале будут вызваны триггеры "*for each row*" для каждой из записей, после чего будет один раз вызван общий триггер. В пакет вы сохраняете значения только одной записи, в случае массового update в момент отработки итогового триггера у вас в переменных пакета будут данные только из последней обновленной записи.

А вашу проблему я предлагаю решить совершенно иным способом. Вам нужен триггер *BEFORE*, в нем вы можете менять значения в записях до того как их запишут на диск:

```
create or replace trigger audit_income_B_IUD
  before insert or update or delete on Sale_income
    for each row
begin
  if inserting or updating then
    :new.last_update_user := user;
    :new.last_update_date := sysdate;
  end if;
  insert into Sale_income_audit ....
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я почему-то был убежден, что нужно использовать только after each row,  а оказалось все так просто